# Traffic light approach strategy

Tags: probability, analysis

When driving a car at a cruising speed, and approaching a red traffic light, it is obviously smart to decelerate as soon as possible to some lower, but highest possible velocity that allow the light switch green just as we cross the stop line. We save time and energy this way.

For the sake of this question we ignore friction. Therefor energy is lost by decelerating (breaking). After all, we have to regain our cruising speed after the light has turned green. In other words, **we want an approach strategy that maximises our minimum velocity**

When approaching a traffic light with a known cycle, the solution is already described in the first paragraph.

But our driver doesn't know the exact cycle length. But they witnessed (in the distance) the light switching to red, and they know the maximum and minimum duration before the light will turn green (with a constant probability between those values).

How should the driver approach the red light, to optimise their energy over all the possible scenarios?

Comment: Optimal how? In terms of energy usage, it would depend a lot on the weight of the car as well as everything else.

Comment: I have a much bigger challenge: What if you have a green light ahead? Do you maintain (or speed up) your speed with the result that either you make it or you have to slam your brakes if it turns yellow? Or do you start to slow down because you feel it can turn yellow any time, thus saving your brake pads (and a lot of energy)? But some people behind you may not like that.

Comment: @MorganRodgers If I understand correctly, what needs to be optimized is the speed of the car when crossing the light. This doesn't depend on the car's weight.

Comment: @MorganRodgers: I don't see how it depends on the weight of the car.

Comment: Without a clear definition of optimality, this isn't a very interesting problem.

Comment: @Leo I don't know that that's clear at all. They mentioned saving energy. My real point is that we have no idea what they mean by "optimality".

Comment: @TonyK The energy saved will depend on velocity and mass, obviously.

Comment: @MorganRodgers: Yes, but the strategy to achieve the maximal saving will be independent of the mass, obviously.

Comment: The highest speed on the stop line means the most energy saved and also most likely the shortest travel time. So we optimize for speed at the stop line. Is this feasable for reopening the question?

Comment: Conserving maximal energy would actually mean to maximise the mean of velocity squared (at the stop line) over all approaches.

Answer (score 2):

I would use geometric progression for the speed.

You drive at speed $v$.

As you first spot the red light, you are at a distance $d$ to the traffic light. Reduce your speed by a factor $a <1$. Now you drive with $a v$. After half the remaining distance to the traffic light, if the lights are still red, reduce again by the same factor. Now you drive with $a^2 v$. Repeat, as long as the light is red.

What happens is the following: The time $t_k$ you need to drive the $k$th segment, after having reduced your speed for the  $k$th time, is
 $t_k = \frac{0.5^k d}{a^k v}$. The total time elapsed for driving $n$ segments is thus
$T_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{0.5^k d}{a^k v} = \frac{d}{v} \frac{1 - 1/(2a)^n}{1 - 1/(2a)}$

This formula allows you to adapt to your previous knowledge (or expectation or risk-aversiveness).

Note that it takes $n\to \infty$ to actually arrive at the traffic light since at $n$, the remaining distance to the traffic light is $0.5^n d$.

If you know nothing and want to take no risk of having to stop, choose $a < 0.5$. Then, for $n \to \infty$, $T_n$ diverges, and you have as much time as you may ever need until the light turns green again. Even if your traffic light was indeed a permanent red, you don't have to worry since you will not reach it in finite time.

If you have an estimate (say, as a very conservative one, the longest time $T^*$ you ever experienced a traffic light to stay red), then you can fit $a$ by roughly setting $T^* =  \frac{d}{v} \frac{1}{1 - 1/(2a)}$. You my adapt this to actual knowledge of the phase time.

What's rather difficult is to adapt it to the *true* remaining "red" time, unless you take other factors into account, e.g. how many cars are standing waiting at the red light, which at this time of a normal day means that the light is red already for time $t$ ... this is very unreliable information.

Lastly, if your plan is to "arrive" at some braking distance $d^*$ from the traffic light with some remaining speed $v^*$ (which would allow you to brake), then you should have, after $n$ segments, $d^* = 0.5^n d$ and $v^* = a^n v$, hence set $$a = (\frac{v^*}{v})^{1/(\log(d^*/d) / \log(0.5))}$$ and better have a processor to do this for you on site...

Comment: Sounds great! Especially as there is always some energy conserved, even if the light stays red. I still wonder how to decide if this is energy-wise best..